# ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(194)] Invalid first_paint error using Selenium Python ChromeDriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I am just starting to learn selenium but when I run the program it opens the chrome window for few seconds and then closes giving the error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52176/devtools/browser/b5500769-96fb-4f99-85df-b05a11157eea
[11368:11308:0324/102029.198:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(194)] Invalid first_paint 5.369 s for first_meaningful_paint 5.287 s
[11368:11308:0324/102029.486:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(194)] Invalid first_paint 5.369 s for first_meaningful_paint 5.287 s
[11368:11308:0324/102029.757:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(194)] Invalid first_paint 5.369 s for first_meaningful_paint 5.287 s
[11368:11308:0324/102030.045:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(194)] Invalid first_paint 5.369 s for first_meaningful_paint 5.287 s
```

As I am new to selenium I dont have any idea why this error is showing up.

Comment: please add the code snippet to better understand your problem, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
[11368:11308:0324/102029.198:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(194)] Invalid first_paint 5.369 s for first_meaningful_paint 5.287 s
[11368:11308:0324/102029.486:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(194)] Invalid first_paint 5.369 s for first_meaningful_paint 5.287 s
[11368:11308:0324/102029.757:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(194)] Invalid first_paint 5.369 s for first_meaningful_paint 5.287 s
```

...indicates that there is a mismatch between the binary versions you are using.

---

### Details

As per the [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3341#c1) within the [discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3341):

> The supported configuration is to always match the version between
> Chrome and ChromeDriver - so when you are using Chrome 80, you should
> use Chrome 80. It is also possible to run ChromeDriver N with Chrome
> N+1, but this will always generate the warning you see. Most
> operations will complete successfully, but it is not the recommended
> approach.
>
> The solution is to upgrade ChromeDriver to version 80:
> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

---

### Solution

You need to ensure:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to [ChromeDriver v110.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=110.0.5481.77/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=110.0* (as per [chromedriver=110.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/110.0.5481.77/notes.txt)).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.8.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).