# Using the visual code the chrome tab closes

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using the visual code for a long time but I was forced to install once again because my PC OS was gone. When I tried to use te program this appear on the console. The program itself work but at the end the chrome tab close.

[12904:2880:0419/145538.693:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(178)] Invalid first_paint (unset) for first_image_paint 2.993 s
[12904:2880:0419/145538.701:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(178)] Invalid first_paint 3.124 s for first_image_paint 2.993 s
[12904:2880:0419/145538.846:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(178)] Invalid first_paint 3.124 s for first_image_paint 2.993 s
[12904:2880:0419/145539.031:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(178)] Invalid first_paint 3.124 s for first_image_paint 2.993 s
[12904:2880:0419/145539.238:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(178)] Invalid first_paint 3.124 s for first_image_paint 2.993 s
[12904:2880:0419/145539.305:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(178)] Invalid first_paint 3.124 s for first_image_paint 2.993 s
[12904:2880:0419/145539.576:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(178)] Invalid first_paint 3.124 s for first_image_paint 2.993 s
[12904:2880:0419/145539.872:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(178)] Invalid first_paint 3.124 s for first_image_paint 2.993 s
[12904:2880:0419/145539.934:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(178)] Invalid first_paint 3.124 s for first_image_paint 2.993 s

First of all I restarted and turned it on again and then reinstalled the program but the problem persisted

Comment: what is the need to show the same error 9 times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR:page\_load\_metrics\_update\_dispatcher.cc(194)\] Invalid first\_paint error using Selenium Python ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75830184/errorpage-load-metrics-update-dispatcher-cc194-invalid-first-paint-error-usi)

Comment: It's literally the first time I've used stack. I'm still getting used to the error messages